# Do marksdwarves require a separate archery and barracks?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I've set up a marksdwarf squad, and I've got their equipment sorted out already, but next is the barracks - do I need a separate barracks and firing range, or can they be in the same room?

Answer (score 1):

They can use the same barracks and training rooms as any other squad, as long as you specify in the room menu that the squad can use the room for training/sleep. But if you do let multiple squads use one room, make sure the capacity of it is sufficient, otherwise you might not reach the peak efficiency.

Reasons to use one room for all squads: All your fighter dorfs are in one place.
Reasons not to: Possibly slightly worse management - with separate barracks, you can put specific weapons and equipment in them, and dorfs will have to walk shorter distance for them. But it requires more planning.

As a side note, letting dorfs train in the same room others sleep can lead to FUN. (bad sleep from the noise and some entertaining accidents)